# Cannot move html button to the right

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie to html and css. I am trying to move the button "dropbtn" to the right side of my webpage, but it remains on the left side. I have tried using float, align, right, text-align but they all don't seem to work. I have also tried using the tag !important but that does not help either.

```css
.mystyle{
     height: 90px;
     width: 254px;
     color: white;
     font-size: smaller;
    }
    .flip-container{
     perspective: 1000px;
    }
    .flip-container:hover .flipper,
    .flip-container.hover .flipper{
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .flip-container,
    .front
    .back{
     height: 200px;
        width: 260px;
    }
    .flipper{
     transition: 1s;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
     position: relative;
    }
    .front,
    .back{
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .front{
        text-align: center;
        color: black !important;
        z-index: 2;
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        
    }
    .back{
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    footer{
        background: #aaa;
        color: white;
    }
    .edit{
        float: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    nav{
    
        height: 6cm;
        background-image: url("bg.jpg");
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;   
    }
    
    
    /* Dropdown Button */
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
      }
      
      /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
      .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      
      /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
      }
      
      /* Links inside the dropdown */
      .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
      }
      
      /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
      .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
      
      /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
      
      /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
      .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>webpage title</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            <script src="js/restaurants.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body onload="getRestaurantData()">
            <!-- This is where top navigation html codes is -->
            <div w3-include-html="top-navigation.html"></div>
            <!-- This is the container that holds the initial message, heading, and movies -->
    
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            <div class="container">
            <!-- The message will be shown when the page loads and will
            disappear after the movies are loaded -->
                <div class="row" id="parent">
                    Retrieving movies from database... Please wait...<br><br>
                    If you are seeing this message for a long time, it is likely
                    that you have a JavaScript error. Troubleshoot your script by
                    using the browser console panel now. Please use either Firefox
                    or Chrome to render this webpage.
                </div>
                <p>
                    <!-- This is the heading showing how many movies are there -->
                    <h3 id="summary"></h3>
                </p>
                <!-- Displays thumbnails of the movies here -->
                <div id="restaurantsTable" class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <!-- Include footer here -->
            <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
        </body>
    <script src="js/w3.js"></script>
    <script>
            //to bring in other HTML on the fly into this page
            w3.includeHTML();
    </script>
    </html>
```

Cannot move html button to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code you posted is that you've added `display: inline-block;` to the `dropdown` class.  This means that the `div` marked with `dropdown` class will by default only take up the space required to render its children.  Unlike `display: inline;`, however, `inline-block` elements will respond to setting `width` and `height` properties on the element or its class.  So, if you just want to set the `width: 100%;` property on the class, as shown [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1b26uf4v/), you'll then be able to use `text-align: right;`.

Like others have suggested, you could use set the `display` property to `flex`, which gives a little more control to you when trying to position children within the containing element.  There are also some compatibility issues with older browsers (mostly IE < 11).  Probably not that big of a deal at this point.

But the root cause is the `display: inline-block;` property.  If that weren't set I suspect most of your other attempts may have worked, as there are many other ways to properly position the button the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.mystyle{
    height: 90px;
    width: 254px;
    color: white;
    font-size: smaller;
}
.flip-container{
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front
.back{
    height: 200px;
    width: 260px;
}
.flipper{
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.front,
.back{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.front{
    text-align: center;
    color: black !important;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);

}
.back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
footer{
    background: #aaa;
    color: white;
}
.edit{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

nav{

    height: 6cm;
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;   
}


/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
  }

  /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    right:0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

.dropdown-menu.show {
    display: block;
    right: 0px !important;
    left: initial !important;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 56px, 0px) !important;
}

  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

  /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>webpage title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
        
    </head>
<body onload="getRestaurantData()">
        <!-- This is where top navigation html codes is -->
        <div w3-include-html="top-navigation.html"></div>
        <!-- This is the container that holds the initial message, heading, and movies -->

  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="dropdown float-right">
      <button class="dropbtn" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

        <div class="container">
        <!-- The message will be shown when the page loads and will
        disappear after the movies are loaded -->
            <div class="row" id="parent">
                Retrieving movies from database... Please wait...<br><br>
                If you are seeing this message for a long time, it is likely
                that you have a JavaScript error. Troubleshoot your script by
                using the browser console panel now. Please use either Firefox
                or Chrome to render this webpage.
            </div>
            <p>
                <!-- This is the heading showing how many movies are there -->
                <h3 id="summary"></h3>
            </p>
            <!-- Displays thumbnails of the movies here -->
            <div id="restaurantsTable" class="row"></div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <!-- Include footer here -->
        <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
    </body>
<script>
        //to bring in other HTML on the fly into this page
        w3.includeHTML();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/restaurants.js"></script>
</html>
```

Just simply changes in your `HTML` and `CSS`

```css
.mystyle{
    height: 90px;
    width: 254px;
    color: white;
    font-size: smaller;
}
.flip-container{
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front
.back{
    height: 200px;
    width: 260px;
}
.flipper{
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.front,
.back{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.front{
    text-align: center;
    color: black !important;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);

}
.back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
footer{
    background: #aaa;
    color: white;
}
.edit{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

nav{

    height: 6cm;
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;   
}


/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
  }

  /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    right:0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

  /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>webpage title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/restaurants.js"></script>
    </head>
<body onload="getRestaurantData()">
        <!-- This is where top navigation html codes is -->
        <div w3-include-html="top-navigation.html"></div>
        <!-- This is the container that holds the initial message, heading, and movies -->

  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="dropdown float-right">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>

        <div class="container">
        <!-- The message will be shown when the page loads and will
        disappear after the movies are loaded -->
            <div class="row" id="parent">
                Retrieving movies from database... Please wait...<br><br>
                If you are seeing this message for a long time, it is likely
                that you have a JavaScript error. Troubleshoot your script by
                using the browser console panel now. Please use either Firefox
                or Chrome to render this webpage.
            </div>
            <p>
                <!-- This is the heading showing how many movies are there -->
                <h3 id="summary"></h3>
            </p>
            <!-- Displays thumbnails of the movies here -->
            <div id="restaurantsTable" class="row"></div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <!-- Include footer here -->
        <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
    </body>
<script src="js/w3.js"></script>
<script>
        //to bring in other HTML on the fly into this page
        w3.includeHTML();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: yep, this works, but when I move my cursor to any part of the body on the webpage, the button gets triggered. Is there a fix to it?

Comment: Check again i have made some changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this easily while using CSS Flexbox. Avoid using things like `float`, this is considered a bad practice in current days of web development, because it can be solved in a better way.

Add `display: flex` to the parent of `.dropbtn` (in this case `.dropdown`) and add `margin-left: auto` to `.dropbtn` to move it completely to the right side of the page.

Updated styling for these two classes:

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
```

Read more about [using CSS Flexbox at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
.mystyle {
  height: 90px;
  width: 254px;
  color: white;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front .back {
  height: 200px;
  width: 260px;
}

.flipper {
  transition: 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  text-align: center;
  color: black !important;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

footer {
  background: #aaa;
  color: white;
}

.edit {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

nav {
  height: 6cm;
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>webpage title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/restaurants.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="getRestaurantData()">
  <!-- This is where top navigation html codes is -->
  <div w3-include-html="top-navigation.html"></div>
  <!-- This is the container that holds the initial message, heading, and movies -->

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- The message will be shown when the page loads and will
        disappear after the movies are loaded -->
    <div class="row" id="parent">
      Retrieving movies from database... Please wait...<br><br> If you are seeing this message for a long time, it is likely that you have a JavaScript error. Troubleshoot your script by using the browser console panel now. Please use either Firefox or
      Chrome to render this webpage.
    </div>
    <p>
      <!-- This is the heading showing how many movies are there -->
      <h3 id="summary"></h3>
    </p>
    <!-- Displays thumbnails of the movies here -->
    <div id="restaurantsTable" class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <!-- Include footer here -->
  <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
</body>
<script src="js/w3.js"></script>
<script>
  //to bring in other HTML on the fly into this page
  w3.includeHTML();
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `float:right` to the div that has class dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.mystyle{
    height: 90px;
    width: 254px;
    color: white;
    font-size: smaller;
}

.dropdown{
float: right !important;
}



.flip-container{
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front
.back{
    height: 200px;
    width: 260px;
}
.flipper{
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.front,
.back{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.front{
    text-align: center;
    color: black !important;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);

}
.back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
footer{
    background: #aaa;
    color: white;
}
.edit{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

nav{

    height: 6cm;
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;   
}


/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
  }

  /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

  /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>webpage title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/restaurants.js"></script>
    </head>
<body onload="getRestaurantData()">
        <!-- This is where top navigation html codes is -->
        <div w3-include-html="top-navigation.html"></div>
        <!-- This is the container that holds the initial message, heading, and movies -->

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        <div class="container">
        <!-- The message will be shown when the page loads and will
        disappear after the movies are loaded -->
            <div class="row" id="parent">
                Retrieving movies from database... Please wait...<br><br>
                If you are seeing this message for a long time, it is likely
                that you have a JavaScript error. Troubleshoot your script by
                using the browser console panel now. Please use either Firefox
                or Chrome to render this webpage.
            </div>
            <p>
                <!-- This is the heading showing how many movies are there -->
                <h3 id="summary"></h3>
            </p>
            <!-- Displays thumbnails of the movies here -->
            <div id="restaurantsTable" class="row"></div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <!-- Include footer here -->
        <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
    </body>
<script src="js/w3.js"></script>
<script>
        //to bring in other HTML on the fly into this page
        w3.includeHTML();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 .dropdown {
    float: right;
  }
```

Add this to you style.